# PyQt5: How to set a priority to a pyqtSignal?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, signals-slots, python-3.7

#### 1. Background info

I'm working in `Python 3.7`. The python Qt version `Pyqt5` enables you to fire custom pyqt signals. For example:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MyClass(QObject):
    mysignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mysignal.connect(self.bar)
        return

    def foo(self):
        self.mysignal.emit("foobar")
        return

    @pyqtSlot
    def bar(self, mystr):
        print("signal received: {0}".format(mystr))
        return
```

#### 2. The problem

PyQt starts an *event listener loop* in the main thread: it waits for incoming events on a queue and processes them one-by-one. Most of these events are user-invoked things like pushing a button, clicking something, ...

If you fire pyqt signals programatically, as in the `foo()` function above, you also push events onto this queue (I think). That shouldn't be a big deal, unless you fire too many pyqt signals in a short burst. The queue is overwhelmed and user events don't get processed in time. The user sees a freezed GUI. *Yikes!*

#### 3. Solution

One way to tackle this problem could be assigning low priorities to programatically fired pyqt signal. Is this possible? How?
If not - do you know other ways to solve the problem?

Comment: There are no priorities in the signals, in what case does that problem happen to you? I've worked with Qt for years and I've never had that problem, you could provide a [mcve], I think you have a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). For me your problem is design.

Comment: You've got this totally backwards. By default, signals will block because they are ***not*** posted as events. All connected slots are called *synchronously*, which stops further processing of the event-queue. Because of this, Qt supports [queued connections](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), which ***do*** post signals as events. This allows pending events to be processed *before* invoking any slots connected to the signal, thus preventing any blocking of the gui. Cross-thread signals automatically use queued connections for precisiely this reason.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of direct connections (sender and receiver in the same thread), the slot will be directly called when you emit your signal.

So, in your example, you can replace your *emit* by a direct call to `self.bar`.

But, if your slot is too long, the event loop has to wait before it will be able to process the user events.

If your UI is freezing when you call your slot, that means you should use another thread to let the event loop process user events.